# Javascript textbox either 1 can be entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had 2 textbox, but only 1 can be enter and cannot enter both fields. For example if I enter value in input1, input2 is disable. if both value is 0 both field disable to false.

Any help here?

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");


function myFunction() {
  if (input1 != 0 && input2 == 0){
    document.getElementById("input2").disabled = true;
    //ALERT(1);
  }else if(input1 == 0 && input2 != 0){
    //ALERT(2);
    document.getElementById("input1").disabled = true;
  }else if(input1 == 0 && input2 == 0){
    //ALERT(3);
    document.getElementById("input1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("input2").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" style="width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" value="0.00" onchange="myFunction()"/>
<input id="input2" style="width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" value="0.00" onchange="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: You have no events. Your code runs once when the page loads.

Comment: what event should I use? onchange? onfocus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event, which fires when an element has lost focus.

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

function myFunction() {
  input1.addEventListener("blur", event => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    input2.disabled = !!value && value != 0;
  });

  input2.addEventListener("blur", event => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    input1.disabled = !!value && value != 0;
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" style="width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" value="0.00" onchange="myFunction()" />
<input id="input2" style="width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" value="0.00" onchange="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: but it only work for the first time. if I set value to 0 back, how do I set  both field can be enter again.

Comment: I see now, please check my updated answer if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, thank you, because 0 is default value for both fields

Comment: Awesome! I've fixed the logic to work with your initial example `"0.00"` by using double equals `==` which will perform a type conversion when comparing.

Comment: nice.really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code example.

```js
$(function() {
  function isEmpty(fObj) {
    console.log($(fObj).val());
    return ($(fObj).val() == "" ? true : false);
  }

  $(".form").on("change blur", "input", function() {
    if (!isEmpty(this)) {
      $(".form input").not(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "0") {
      $(".form input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <input id="input1" style="width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" value="0.00" />
  <input id="input2" style="width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" value="0.00" />
</div>
```

You can use `change` or `blur` callbacks and examine the target (`this`) of the event.